# where can i find public domain open source list of softwares

Tags: open-source, licensing, indexing

i like to browse open source software that are released as public domain type of software license , is there such list ? 
if i think about it is there some kind of index that sort open source applications by license ? 
Thanks

Comment: What sort of software are you looking for? What are you trying to achieve? How is this programming related?

Comment: [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) [google code](http://code.google.com/hosting/)

Comment: You will want to go back to the newsgroups particularly comp.sources.unix and scan for public domain, I am putting together a collection of work I have found there https://github.com/cmgraff/PublicDomain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/) is an open source directory which lists projects, listing their creators and people using it.

You can search for software with a specific license, e.g.
[license:Public Domain](http://www.ohloh.net/search?q=license%3APublic+Domain)

Answer (score 1):

[freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net/)

> freshmeat maintains the Web's largest
>   index of Unix and cross-platform
>   software, themes and related
>   "eye-candy", and Palm OS software.
>   Thousands of applications, which are
>   preferably released under an open
>   source license, are meticulously
>   cataloged in the freshmeat database,
>   and links to new applications are
>   added daily. Each entry provides a
>   description of the software, links to
>   download it and to obtain more
>   information, and a history of the
>   project's releases, so readers can
>   keep up-to-date on the latest
>   developments.

Answer (score 0):

[CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com) is a good source for .NET open source stuff.